# How to cascade insert a parent, child, and list of combinations in Fluent-NHibernate

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using SQLite and I've these three tables:

`User (Id, Name)
 Project (Id, Name)
 ProjectUser (UserId, ProjectId)`

But in my mappings, I have only two ClassMaps:  `UserMap` to map User and `ProjectMap` to map Project

In my models `User` has a list of `Project` and `Project` has a list of `User`, a `many-to-many relationship`.

How I can do to create a new instance of User, new instance of Project, add the project in the ProjectList of user, and insert all (user, project and userproject) when I `session.Save(NewUser)`?

Its my actually mappings, which is inverting the columns `ProjectId` and `UserId` on database:

**P.S:**

- I've tried to invert the order of parent/child columns name and tried
  to remove or put `Inverse()` in all combinations, and sometimes I've
  got this error: `Abort due to constraint violation\r\nforeign key
  constraint failed`  and another times I've got the same problem of
  inverting the columns.
- I've tried to use my own proxy to execute `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` after each connection is open.

**PROJECTMAP**

```
Table("TBPROJECT");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.ProjectName).Length(100).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.TeamProjectURL).Length(100).Not.Nullable();

        HasManyToMany(x => x.UserList).Table("TBPROJECTUSER").ParentKeyColumn("UserId").ChildKeyColumn("ProjectId").Inverse();
```

**USERMAP**

```
Table("TBUSER");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.FullName).Length(100).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Username).Length(100).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Email).Length(100).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Password).Length(100).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Department).Length(100).Nullable();

        HasManyToMany(x => x.ProjectList).Table("TBPROJECTUSER").ParentKeyColumn("UserId").ChildKeyColumn("ProjectId").Cascade.All();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that you are naming your columns (`ParentKeyColumn` and `ChildKeyColumn`). If you just name you table and call `Inverse()` or `Cascade.All()`, it will work as you want, due to the fact that fluent nhibernate will create both columns and manage by itself.

On your **ProjectMap**, you can do this:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.UserList).Table("TBPROJECTUSER").Inverse();
```

and on your **UserMap**, you can do this:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.ProjectList).Table("TBPROJECTUSER").Cascade.All();
```